# nfs mount with nfs 3

Tags: nfs

I am running CentOS 6.4 Kernel version 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP and have the following nfs info:

- nfs-utils-lib-1.1.5-6.el6.x86_64
- nfs4-acl-tools-0.3.3-6.el6.x86_64
- nfs-utils-1.2.3-36.el6.x86_64

and am trying to mount an NFS volume with nfs3. I have the following line in my `fstab`:

> 172.16.11.87:/volume1/web /home/nas nfsver=3 rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr(no_root_squach)

When I run `nfsstat` it still shows the client as nfs4

```
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badauth    badclnt    xdrcall
0          0          0          0          0       

Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
1988817    6          1988818
```

**Client nfs v4:**

```
null         read         write        commit       open         open_conf    
0         0% 36943     1% 21606     1% 401       0% 392369   19% 375986   18% 
open_noat    open_dgrd    close        setattr      fsinfo       renew        
0         0% 0         0% 387945   19% 22904     1% 3         0% 2914      0% 
setclntid    confirm      lock         lockt        locku        access       
1         0% 1         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 97856     4% 
getattr      lookup       lookup_root  remove       rename       link         
613996   30% 29888     1% 1         0% 1248      0% 253       0% 414       0% 
symlink      create       pathconf     statfs       readlink     readdir      
26        0% 226       0% 2         0% 3         0% 0         0% 3825      0% 
server_caps  delegreturn  getacl       setacl       fs_locations rel_lkowner  
5         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 
exchange_id  create_ses   destroy_ses  sequence     get_lease_t  reclaim_comp 
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 
layoutget    layoutcommit layoutreturn getdevlist   getdevinfo   ds_write     
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 
ds_commit    
0         0%
```

Comment: what OS on your host?

Comment: Sorry should have said that in my original post, its CentOS 6.4

Comment: also post kernel version and nfs client package version, might be helpful as well.

Comment: I have added the kernel and nfs version in my post above

Comment: ok. let me see.

Comment: Let me see version of the server nfs package, it looks like your server is not offering nfs3.

Comment: This is just a warning: Don't do it. NFSv3 is ancient and unreliable. You should be using version 4 unless the server is also ancient and doesn't support it (in which case it should be taken out back and shot).

Comment: nfs is ancient and unreliable?  i'll give you the ancient part but unreliable? citation needed!

Answer (score 8):

You have misspelled nfsvers=3 and no_root_squash.

Comment: Actually, the misspelling is a very likely cause of this error, though I'd expect some kind of error or warning to be indicated for the invalid options.

Comment: I got that from the CentOs site. Changing it has no positive effecting in fixing the problem.

Comment: You have missed the final s off nfsvers in nfsvers=3

Comment: copied from Centos site, doesn't matter though, cause I have posted the real fix above.

Answer (score 6):

nfsvers is an option.

```
<server>:</remote/export> </local/directory> <nfs-type> <options> 0 0
```

It seems that you missed the nsf-type. Changing nfsmount.conf may solve the problem in a system that will never work with nfs4. I have faced the same problem and it was solved like this in your fstab

```
172.16.11.87:/volume1/web /home/nas nfs nfsvers=3 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

So that people can get a real answer to the problem, this is how I solved it:

in the `/etc/nfsmount.conf`:

> change Defaultvers=4 to Defaultvers=3

That's it, it now shows up as

```
nfsstat
Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
6          0          6       

Client nfs v3:
```